# Kubernetes postStart hook leads to race condition

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

I use a MySQL on Kubernetes with a `postStart` hook which should run a query after the start of the database.

This is the relevant part of my `template.yaml`:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ${{APP}}
          image: ${REGISTRY}/${NAMESPACE}/${APP}:${VERSION}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /bin/sh
                  - -c
                  - hostname && sleep 12 && echo $QUERY | /opt/rh/rh-mysql80/root/usr/bin/mysql
                    -h localhost -u root -D grafana
                    -P 3306
          ports:
            - name: tcp3306
              containerPort: 3306
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 3306
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 3306
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            timeoutSeconds: 1
```

When the pod start, the PVC for the database gets corruped and the pod crashes. When I restart the pod, it works. I guess the query runs, when the database is not up yet. I guess this might get fixed with the readinessprobe, but I am not an expert at these topics.

Did anyone else run into a similar issue and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `postStart` will be call at least once but may also be called more than once. This make `postStart` a bad place to run query.

You can set pod `restartPolicy: OnFailure` and run the query in separate MYSQL container. Start your second container with [wait](https://github.com/groundnuty/k8s-wait-for) and run your query. Note that your query should produce idempotent result or your data integrity may breaks; consider when the pod is re-create with the existing data volume.

Comment: thank you for your input, but that´s not really a way I can go, since I would have to write ton of documents and tests for that other pod :-/

Comment: You can run multiple containers in same pod.

Comment: yes, you are right. We decided to go for a quick fix and set the sleep time to 120s, which should be enough. The query checks if tables exist and won´t run a second time anyway